# Instapaper API Access (Full API) - Problem with xAuth

Tags: api, oauth, instapaper

i was playing around with the instapaper full api and im having some trouble with the OAuth api.
MUST i have a token for using the full api or is this optional?

Comment: Well, what does their documentation say about it? =) http://www.instapaper.com/api/full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play with the simple API you need only a user//password

But for the full API you need:
 - a OAuth consumer key 
 - OAuth consumer secret

Those you will obtain after making a request on: [Register New OAuth Application](http://www.instapaper.com/main/request_oauth_consumer_token)

You will need also to have a superscription that cost 1$/month
More info [here](http://www.instapaper.com/subscription) or go in your Instapaper account detail.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You no longer need a premium subscription in order to access the API. It is available for free accounts too.